# ViewPager в BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet

Здравствуйте. Сунул `ViewPager` в `BottomSheet` и пэйджинг `ViewPager` тупит. Тоесть чтобы листнуть `ViewPager` нужно сделать свайп ровно по X. Если свайп неровный, то `BottomSheet` закрывается.

Так серьёзно все, что даже подумал о запрете закрытия.

Comment: Естественно, если у вас на вертикальном свайпе открытие\закрытие ботомшита, что вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: А можно ли как то запретить закрытие ботомшита когда вьюпэйжер скроллится?

Comment: Я не уверен, но у `ViewPager` есть колбэк `OnPageChangeListener` с методом обратного вызова `onPageScrolled()`, который срабатывает при скроллинге пэйджера, а у ботомшита есть метод `setSkipCollapsed()`. Можно попробовать через эти методы как то, наверное.

Comment: Как то вроде можно поймать события касания/отпускания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Помогло переопределение двух методов. В старой логике изменения по Y сравнивались с нулем, поэтому скроллить нужно было ровно горизонтально. Я добавил minChange, который прибавляю или вычитаю (в зависимости от знака сравнения) чтобы стейт не менялся при изменении Y меньше 15 пикселей.

```
public class ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends 
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

private int minChange = 15;

    @Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target, int dx,
                              int dy, int[] consumed) {
    View scrollingChild = mNestedScrollingChildRef.get();
    if (target != scrollingChild) {
        return;
    }
    int currentTop = child.getTop();
    int newTop = currentTop - dy;
    if (dy > 0 + minChange) { // Upward
        if (newTop < mMinOffset) {
            consumed[1] = currentTop - mMinOffset;
            ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -consumed[1]);
            setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
        } else {
            consumed[1] = dy;
            ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -dy);
            setStateInternal(STATE_DRAGGING);
        }
    } else if (dy < 0 - minChange) { // Downward
        if (!ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(target, -1)) {
            if (newTop <= mMaxOffset || mHideable) {
                consumed[1] = dy;
                ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -dy);
                setStateInternal(STATE_DRAGGING);
            } else {
                consumed[1] = currentTop - mMaxOffset;
                ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, -consumed[1]);
                setStateInternal(STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        }
    }
    dispatchOnSlide(child.getTop());
    mLastNestedScrollDy = dy;
    mNestedScrolled = true;
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View target) {
    if (child.getTop() == mMinOffset) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
        return;
    }
    if (target != mNestedScrollingChildRef.get() || !mNestedScrolled) {
        return;
    }
    int top;
    int targetState;
    if (mLastNestedScrollDy > 0 + minChange) {
        top = mMinOffset;
        targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
    } else if (mHideable && shouldHide(child, getYVelocity())) {
        top = mParentHeight;
        targetState = STATE_HIDDEN;
    } else if (mLastNestedScrollDy == 0) {
        int currentTop = child.getTop();
        if (Math.abs(currentTop - mMinOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - mMaxOffset)) {
            top = mMinOffset;
            targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        } else {
            top = mMaxOffset;
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
    } else {
        top = mMaxOffset;
        targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, targetState));
    } else {
        setStateInternal(targetState);
    }
    mNestedScrolled = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Умно :) опробую, отпишусь)